# Is 'to' necessary here?

Tags: prepositions

should it be

> The first thing she did after returning home was slap him

or

> The first thing she did after returning home was to slap him

Comment: You should include the research you’ve done and add more details. If you don’t, it will be put to on hold.

Answer (score 3):

According to the "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language" by Quirk, that "to" in pseudo-cleft sentences with the verb "do" in the subject is optional:

[image: Pseud-cleft sentences with infinitive]

Answer (score 1):

Either works, or potentially “**Her first action, on returning home, was *slapping* him**”.